# Find IDs in one table not present in another table

Tags: python, join, cassandra, cql

Given are two tables in Cassandra:

```
xs (id bigint, x bigint)
0,10
1,11
2,12
3,13
4,14

ys (id bigint, y bigint)
0,100
2,144
4,196
```

In this minimal example I would like to get all rows from `xs` having an `id` not contained in `ys` yet, i.e.

```
select
1,11
3,13
```

How can I achieve this?

Based on the selected rows I want to create new rows in `ys`, basically synchronizing (addition only) `ys` to `xs`.

Here is my code to create the keyspaces/tables:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect()

session.execute('DROP KEYSPACE keyspace_x;')
session.execute('DROP KEYSPACE keyspace_y;')

session.execute('''
    CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_x
    WITH replication = {
        'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
        'replication_factor' : 1
    };''');

session.execute('''
    CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_y
    WITH replication = {
        'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
        'replication_factor' : 1
    };''');

session.execute('''CREATE TABLE keyspace_x.xs (
    id bigint,
    x bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);''');

session.execute('''CREATE TABLE keyspace_y.ys (
    id bigint,
    y bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);''');

session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_x.xs(id, x) VALUES (%s, %s)',(0, 10))
session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_x.xs(id, x) VALUES (%s, %s)',(1, 11))
session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_x.xs(id, x) VALUES (%s, %s)',(2, 12))
session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_x.xs(id, x) VALUES (%s, %s)',(3, 13))
session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_x.xs(id, x) VALUES (%s, %s)',(4, 14))

session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_y.ys(id, y) VALUES (%s, %s)',(0, 100))
session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_y.ys(id, y) VALUES (%s, %s)',(2, 144))
session.execute('INSERT INTO keyspace_y.ys(id, y) VALUES (%s, %s)',(4, 196))
```

In [SQL I would use something like that](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9b5c8/6)

```
SELECT xs.id, xs.x FROM xs
LEFT JOIN ys ON xs.id = ys.id
WHERE ys.id IS NULL;
```

But what about CQL?

Currently I just fetch all IDs from both tables and do a set difference in my application, but I guess this is far from optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no multi-table functionality. [How implement LEFT or RIGHT JOIN using spark-cassandra-connector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32520182/3404097) You can add relational layers onto Cassandra. [How to do a join queries with 2 or more tables in cassandra cql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17248232/3404097) You can fruitlessly search the manual. http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html Re browsing/googling: Other SQL ways to do what you want are `EXCEPT`aka `MINUS` & `NOT IN`. Algebraic functionality is `DIFFERENCE` aka `MINUS` & `ANTIJOIN`).